# PowerPoint hanging on Application.Quit call

Tags: com, powerpoint

Here's the code I'm running:

```
MsoTriState readOnly = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
MsoTriState untitled = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
MsoTriState withWindow = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
string filePath; //some file path to a pptx

ppt.Application app = null;
ppt.Presentations presentations = null;
ppt.Presentation presentation = null;

app = new ppt.Application();
presentations = app.Presentations;
presentation = presentations.Open(filePath, readOnly, untitled, withWindow);

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(presentation);
presentation = null;
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(presentations);
presentations = null;

app.Quit(); //HANGING HERE

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
app = null;
```

It's a very basic code that opens a PowerPoint application and then closes it. However, for some reason, it is hanging on the `app.Quit()` call. Also, I don't know why, but if I comment out the line where I ComRelease presentation, it doesn't hang. An alternative hack is to make app.Visible = msoTrue before calling app.Quit.

Does anyone know what is going on here? Am I messing up my ComRelease procedure?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot offer a solution but only confirm that I can reproduce the behavior. The COM references look fine for me. On my machine Quit clogs the CPU so it seems PowerPoint hangs in an infinite loop. I cannot see how this may be caused by an unreleased reference.

Comment: Forget what I just said. I deactivated an add-in and now it works. Maybe something similar for you as well?

Comment: Oh, I think you might be right. Disabling one of my add-ins seemed to get around that hanging issue. Awesome suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I have a workout for you here.you can found out the running process and kill it through code.

**Code:**

```
 Process[] pros = Process.GetProcesses();
  for (int i = 0; i < pros.Count(); i++)
     {
       if (pros[i].ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("powerpnt"))
            {
              pros[i].Kill();
            }
     }
```